# PowerShell: extract multiple archives - script error

Tags: powershell

I have a folder which contains multiple zip archives. I need to extract all of them into subfolders named the same way initial files are (but without ".zip") To do so I created the following script:

```
$archives = Get-ChildItem . -Filter *.zip
foreach($zip in $archives)
{
Expand-Archive $zip.FullName -DestinationPath "{$zip.BaseName}"
}
```

If I run it the first file in the current folder is unpacked properly but for each subsequent file the folder is created but then there is an error
"Expand-Archive : The path '' either does not exist or is not a valid file system path."
And the folder is empty, nothing is unpacked. I inspect $zip object in a debugger on each iteration, it seems correct.

Any idea why it happens?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the “{ }” from around $zip.basename

Comment: @DougMaurer I tried. In fact, I started this way. Doesn't matter, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$archives = Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Filter *.zip
foreach($zip in $archives)
{
    Expand-Archive $zip.FullName -DestinationPath "$($zip.DirectoryName)\$($zip.BaseName)"
}
```

**UPDATE**

When testing names that include wildcard like '[' or we have to escape them in PowerShell

Example, testing if folder test[3] exists without and with escaping characters

```
C:\> Test-Path C:\temp\test[3]
False

C:\> Test-Path 'C:\temp\test`[2`]'
True
```

As [wildcard characters are not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-7.2), we need to modify script to handle names like test[2].zip

updated code will look like:

```
$archives = Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Filter *.zip
foreach($zip in $archives)
{
    $destination = "$($zip.DirectoryName)\$($zip.BaseName)"
    $destinationWithEscapedName = [WildcardPattern]::Escape($destination)

    $zipName = [WildcardPattern]::Escape($zip.FullName)

    Expand-Archive $zipName -DestinationPath $destination
}
```

Comment: Same result. But by playing a bit more with it I realized that Expand-Archive doesn't accept [] characters in file names though they are allowed in path. Many files there named somehow like archive[01].zip. It creates a proper folder with these characters in a name, that's not an issue, but then refuses to unpack the file to it. A bug?

Comment: It is not a bug, but rather you need to escape wildcard characters. See my update

Comment: Great, it worked! Thanks!